# Fetch data from server - fetching only necessary data vs whole data of an object?

Tags: node.js, performance, rest, web

I would like to know what is the best practice for the following use case:
There is a person object:

```
{
   id: number;
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
   phoneNumber: string;
   address: string
   /* more fields */
}
```

I need to fetch list of people and in the list I only need to display part of the object fields (for example - first and last name), after that the user can choose one from the list which will go to another screen where the person details will be fully displayed (for example - also address, phone number, etc).

Should I fetch from the beginning the whole fields for each person or fetch only necessary fields and fetch the whole data for a specific person only when it is needed?

Are there any best practices rules regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every unnecessary field increases computational time, traffic, latency. You should fetch only necessary fields and then wait for client to request more info.